# Can't pass a parameter with jquery to webapi post method from body

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi which working fine (tested with rest client). I'm trying to call a post method with jQuery.

The parameter sent with both `$.ajax` and `$.post` methods is empty.

The model of data passed in form body is:

```
public class SearchCandidatCriteria
{
    public string Nom;
    public string Sexe;
    public string Ville;
    public int SituationFamiliale;
    public int NiveauAcademique;
    public int ServiceNational;
    public string PosteDemande;
}
```

The jQuery method is:

```
$.ajax({
            'url': 'http://localhost:6232/api/Candidats/rechercher',
            'method': 'POST',
            'data': JSON.stringify('{"Nom":"","Sexe":"F","Ville":"","SituationFamiliale":0,"NiveauAcademique":";n,n,;n,;n","ServiceNational":"2","PosteDemande":"120"}'),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

The parameter received by the controller is always null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constructing the request incorrectly

Build the JavaScript object and then stringify it

```
var data = {Nom:"",Sexe:"F",Ville:"",SituationFamiliale:0,NiveauAcademique:";n,n,;n,;n",ServiceNational:"2",PosteDemande:"120"};
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:6232/api/Candidats/rechercher',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The model should also use properties instead of fields

```
public class SearchCandidatCriteria {
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Sexe { get; set; }
    public string Ville { get; set; }
    public int SituationFamiliale { get; set; }
    public int NiveauAcademique { get; set; }
    public int ServiceNational { get; set; }
    public string PosteDemande { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nkosi . there was two errors in my code : 1. the worg buidling of the data set with ajax and (2) the missing of getters and setters in my class.

Comment: @alisriti yes that is an accurate assessment of the error made.